# How to call a class in PHP script within the project?

Tags: php, laravel

I have want to create a PHP script to query all the accounts. Since I already have the class, that already does all of that, I want to leverage it and use it.

I've tried this. I create a file call `syncuserstable.php`:

```
<?php

use App\VSE;

$accounts = VSE::account_all();
dd($accounts);

?>
```

I run:

```
php syncuserstable.php
```

I got:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\VSE' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/syncuserstable.php on line 5

App\VSE:

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    class VSE {
        public static function account_all() {
            $url = env('API_HOST').'vse/accounts';
            return Helper::getData($url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Missing `;` after `use App\VSE`

Comment: After adding that `;`, still got this .

Comment: no way. Are you sure you saved the change?

Comment: where is defined the function `account_all()`?

Comment: Yes sir > Save > and re run > php syncuserstable.php

Comment: Define here : /app/VSE.php

Comment: Please do not remove the previous error from your question. Next viewers got confused. Also, check out my updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic missed semi-colon :)

And, after fixing this, you got another error and updated your question. For your new problem, you need a backslash before APP.

```
<?php

use \App\VSE;

$accounts = VSE::account_all();
dd($accounts);

?>
```

However, there is no guarantee running a solo file in a Laravel project be successful.

For sure, there are dependencies and autoload considerations you should consider.

In your VSE class, you are using laravel functions which are not known when you run a php file in shell.

Comment: Common that is not the point guys ! I've added it, I still get this `Fatal error: Class 'App\VSE' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/syncuserstable.php on line 5`

Comment: @ihue, but that is not what you show in the question, you are showing the error that the answer above correctly answers. The new error is another error.

Comment: That's a different error. There is no such class. Do you even read the error message?

Comment: Its possible that the class can not be accessed cause there is no autoloader too.

Comment: `use \App\VSE;` --> Still seeing `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\VSE' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/syncuserstable.php on line 5`

Comment: @ihue Please consider the comment Jite said. You need to be sure it's being loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The Error says it all, PHP interpreter encountered the T_VARIABLE `$accounts` but was expecting a ',' or ';' before that.

In this case a semicolon at the end of Line 3 will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed I have to add this `require_once "vendor/autoload.php";`

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use \App\VSE;

// require_once('/app/VSE.php');

$accounts = VSE::account_all();
dd($accounts);

?>
```

---

Now, I get

```
array:10 [
  0 => array:28 [
    "email_address" => "admin@benunets.com"
    "password" => "admin"
    "account_id" => 1000
    "account_type" => "admin"
    "name_prefix" => null
    "first_name" => null
    "middle_names" => null
    "last_name" => "Admin"
    "name_suffix" => null
    "non_person_name" => false
    "dba" => ""
    "display_name" => "Admin"
    "address1" => "111 Park Ave"
    "address2" => "Floor 4"
    "address3" => "Suite 4011"
    "city" => "New York"
    "state" => "NY"
    "postal_code" => "10022"
    "nation_code" => "USA"
    "phone1" => "212-555-1212"
    "phone2" => ""
    "phone3" => ""
    "time_zone_offset_from_utc" => -5
    "customer_type" => 2
    "last_updated_utc_in_secs" => 1446127072
    "longitude" => null
    "latitude" => null
    "altitude" => null
  ]
  1 => array:28 [
    "email_address" => "mhn@benu.com"
    "password" => "benu123"
    "account_id" => 1002
    "account_type" => "customer"
    "name_prefix" => ""
    "first_name" => "MHN"
    "middle_names" => ""
    "last_name" => "User"
    "name_suffix" => ""
    "non_person_name" => false
    "dba" => ""
    "display_name" => "MHNUser"
    "address1" => "11 Peterborough Street"
    "address2" => ""
    "address3" => ""
    "city" => "Boston"
    "state" => "MA"
    "postal_code" => "02215"
    "nation_code" => "USA"
    "phone1" => "44444"
    "phone2" => ""
    "phone3" => ""
    "time_zone_offset_from_utc" => -5
    "customer_type" => 2
    "last_updated_utc_in_secs" => 1469132442
    "longitude" => -71.0957612
    "latitude" => 42.3442383
    "altitude" => 0
  ]
```

Comment: Cool, so you are getting the result. Thanks to @Jite